# How to ensure data inserted only once at a time?

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is how my JSON look like:

```
$return='{"sub":{"2":""},"postcode":"56000","slider1":"100","action":"test"}';


$data = json_decode($return, true);
```

This is how I get the value,

```
$postcode=$data['postcode'];
$budget = $data['slider1'];
$subject =$data['sub'];

var_dump($key =array_keys($data['sub']));// this prints 0=>2

foreach($key as $key1=>$key2)
{
     $key1;//prints 0
     $key2;//prints 2
}
 $key2;//prints 2
```

I'm inserting data like this:

```
try {
  //$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', $username, $password);
  //$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php');
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test (postcode,budget,subject) VALUES(:postcode,:budget,:subject)');
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':postcode' => $postcode,
    ':budget'=> $budget,
    ':subject'=> $key2
  ));

  # Affected Rows?
  $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The above query inserts data twice into the database. I checked the network tab in the chrome dev tool, it shows the request for this file is sent twice.

Is there a way to insert data only once at a time? I mean is there a way to place to restriction on the query?

EDITED

AJAX

```
$("document").ready(function(){
          $(".form").submit(function(){
            var data = {
              "action": "test"
            };
            data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "writedb.php", //Relative or absolute path to writedb.php file


    data: data,
                  success: function(data) {
    //.....
    }
```

Comment: @anantkumarsingh, I managed to solve that issue, now a new one..Please check my edited post above

Comment: @anantkumarsingh, via ajax, pls check above , added my ajax code

Comment: @anantkumarsingh, I tried but still the same!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79307/discussion-between-anant-kumar-singh-and-sherly).